# Error: request for member 'y' in something not a structure or union

Tags: c

I have problem with compilation.

This is my main:

```
int main(void) {

    TP_Init();

    Coordinate *dotyk;

    while( 1 )
    {
        dotyk = Read_Ads7846();

        int xx = *dotyk.x;
        int yy = *dotyk.y;

        TP_DrawPoint(xx,yy);
    }
}
```

My function  Read_Ads looks:

```
Coordinate *Read_Ads7846(void) {

    static Coordinate  screen;
    int m0,m1,m2,TP_X[1],TP_Y[1],temp[3];
    uint8_t count=0;
    int buffer[2][9]={{0},{0}};  
    do                         
    {          
        TP_GetAdXY(TP_X,TP_Y);  
        buffer[0][count]=TP_X[0];  
        buffer[1][count]=TP_Y[0];
        count++;  
    }
    while(!TP_INT_IN&& count<9);  
    if(count==9)  
    {  
        temp[0]=(buffer[0][0]+buffer[0][1]+buffer[0][2])/3;
        temp[1]=(buffer[0][3]+buffer[0][4]+buffer[0][5])/3;
        temp[2]=(buffer[0][6]+buffer[0][7]+buffer[0][8])/3;

        m0=temp[0]-temp[1];
        m1=temp[1]-temp[2];
        m2=temp[2]-temp[0];

        m0=m0>0?m0:(-m0);
        m1=m1>0?m1:(-m1);
        m2=m2>0?m2:(-m2);
        if( m0>THRESHOLD  &&  m1>THRESHOLD  &&  m2>THRESHOLD )
            return 0;
        if(m0<m1)
        {
            if(m2<m0) 
                screen.x=(temp[0]+temp[2])/2;
            else 
                screen.x=(temp[0]+temp[1])/2;   
        }
        else if(m2<m1) 
          screen.x=(temp[0]+temp[2])/2;
        else 
          screen.x=(temp[1]+temp[2])/2;

        temp[0]=(buffer[1][0]+buffer[1][1]+buffer[1][2])/3;
        temp[1]=(buffer[1][3]+buffer[1][4]+buffer[1][5])/3;
        temp[2]=(buffer[1][6]+buffer[1][7]+buffer[1][8])/3;
        m0=temp[0]-temp[1];
        m1=temp[1]-temp[2];
        m2=temp[2]-temp[0];
        m0=m0>0?m0:(-m0);
        m1=m1>0?m1:(-m1);
        m2=m2>0?m2:(-m2);
        if(m0>THRESHOLD&&m1>THRESHOLD&&m2>THRESHOLD)
            return 0;

        if(m0<m1)
        {
            if(m2<m0) 
                screen.y=(temp[0]+temp[2])/2;
            else 
                screen.y=(temp[0]+temp[1])/2;   
        }
        else if(m2<m1) 
            screen.y=(temp[0]+temp[2])/2;
        else
            screen.y=(temp[1]+temp[2])/2;

        return &screen;
    }  
    return 0; 
}
```

I got the error:

> request for member 'y' in something not a structure or union

I thought I need to use -> operator but it causes error too.

Can you explain what is wrong ?

Comment: You may find [**Operator Precedence in C**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) educational, particularly where `'*'` and `'.'` occur in the table. Hint: your `'.'` it taking precedence over your `'*'`.

Comment: There is a major problem, other than the incorrect use of operator presidence).  namely, most of the time the function Read_Ads7846() is often returning '0' I.E. null.  When the main() code tries to dereference the 'null, the program will crash.  Therefore, the returned pointer must be checked for not null before using it.

Comment: As a side note.  The C language does not allow the definition of a stack variable anywhere but immediately after a '{' so you must be using a C++ compiler.  the habit of declaring stack variables in C, elsewhere than immediately after a '{', will cause you lots of grief in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

You need `->` instead `.` because of structure pointer and remove `*` before it.

it should be

```
int xx = dotyk->x;
int yy = dotyk->y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Jayesh is right with his answer, but to clarify things I think it's important that you know the difference between your code and his answer.

Your problem is you assumed that * operator has higher precedence than ***"."***. And that's wrong assumption.

If you put (*dotyk).y it woult work as fine as ->.

***"->"*** is just a shortcut for (*something).member.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `dotyk` is a `Coordinate` (which is a typedef of a struct) pointer.
Now, when you try to access your variable variables (the variables that are in that structure) you did so:

```
int yy = *dotyk.y;
```

The problem is that as there are mathmatic operators with order of doing each (`*` and `/` before `+` and `- for example) so there is an order in C operators.

In C, `.` goes before `*` so what you are doing is actually calling a variable y in the address of the pointer ITSELF (`dotyk`) and not the address of WHERE IT IS POINTING TO (the structure).

There are two solution:

1. Use brackets.

   int yy = *dotyk.y;
   turns to

   int yy = (*dotyk).y;
   so that you'll mention that you want the operator `*` to be performed first so the Y variable request would be performed on the content of the pointer (where it is pointing to) and not the pointer itself.
2. Use `->` operator.

The `->` operator is very useful when it comes to structure pointers.

Instead of writing `int yy = *dotyk.y;` you would just write `int yy = dotyk->y;` and that would say something like "Hey, I want you to treat `dotyk` as a pointer and lead me to the Y variable that can be found where it is pointing towards".

Hope I've helped.